# How to set date format when sending DocuSign via REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign [REST API](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/) via the [DocuSign.eSign](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/) library on Nuget.

I am able to create and send an envelope via the rest API sandbox, and it all works except the SignedDate tab which is always in US date format.

I have set the Admin account I use to send the requests to UK format dates, but when the envelope is opened on DocuSign by a recipient the date is always in US format.

I also tried setting the language of the recipient to en_GB to see if that would work. Anyone else had this issue?

Comment: A caution to anyone who uses the DocuSign.eSign library from Nuget. This *is not* a compiled DLL but actually loads the source code into the /packages folder along with a solution file. I suggest you fork and turn it into a real Nuget pacakge like I did.

Comment: The latest version ([2.1.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/2.1.3)) of the DocuSign.eSign.dll is a compiled DLL. Source code is no longer downloaded into the /packages folder.

Comment: Thanks @CodingDawg !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to set the format of the DocuSign dateSigned tab is through the admin console. Please ensure that you are creating an envelope for the same account in which you are also updating the format in the admin console.

Comment: Thanks - are there different settings for sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

Further to Luis' answer, it's worth noting that the format for 'dateSigned' tab is stored separately to the sender's date preference, and from the account's Regional Settings.

The dateSigned formatting settings can be found in Admin > Signing and Sending > Signing Settings.